# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, junit, wicket

I am running Junit test, getting error:

GroupOptionInputPanelTest.java:

```
public void setUp() {           
        groupOptionInputPanel = new GroupOptionInputPanel(TEST_ID, new Model(new ArrayList()), null);
    }
```

GroupOptionInputPanel.java:

```
public GroupOptionInputPanel(String id, IModel model, final Form parentForm) {
        this(id, model, parentForm, false);
    }
```

...

```
ListView options = new GroupElementListView("options", getSelectionGroup().getSelectionOptions(), getInitTabIndex()) {
```

..

```
public abstract class AbstractOptionPanel extends Panel {
public SelectionGroup getSelectionGroup() {
        return (SelectionGroup) getModel().getObject();
    }
```

error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
    at com.bgc.ordering.wizard.front.groupoptions.AbstractOptionPanel.getSelectionGroup(AbstractOptionPanel.java:33)
    at com.bgc.ordering.wizard.front.groupoptions.GroupOptionInputPanel.<init>(GroupOptionInputPanel.java:54)
    at com.bgc.ordering.wizard.front.groupoptions.GroupOptionInputPanel.<init>(GroupOptionInputPanel.java:47)
```

How can I solve this error?

```
public GroupOptionInputPanel(String id, IModel model, final Form parentForm, final boolean canDisplayExclamationMark) {
        super(id, model);
        this.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        ListView options = new GroupElementListView("options", getSelectionGroup().getSelectionOptions(), getInitTabIndex()) {


  public Model(Serializable object)
    {
        setObject(object);
    }
```

Model is Wicket API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model consists of an `ArrayList` instance and you are trying to cast it to `SelectionGroup`. `new Model(new SelectionGroup())` should fix it.

Comment: @kasim then you can't fix it. You expect to have a SelectionGroup instance - if you can't create it somehow, you can't get it. (Well, you can use reflection, but that would be odd)

Comment: i doubt with  GroupOptionInputPanel parameter arrayList.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: still, nothing I can add to my answer - the problem remains the same.